# How could I en mass change divs in jquery randomly?

Tags: jquery, setinterval, opacity

Here's a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zyqqLtk4/

Basically I have one div that twinkles because when a random number is generated, opacity is set as < 0.5 then -> 0, else = 1.0. 
How could I use the following:

```
var opacity = 0;
var myVar = setInterval(function () {
    opacity = Math.random();
    if (opacity > 0.5) {
        opacity = 1;
    } else {
        opacity = 0;
    }
    $('.point1').css('opacity', opacity);

}, 50);
```

But on a hundred divs for instance with each being a completely different random value (meaning they aren't tied together by the same binary opacity).

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `setInterval`?

Comment: For the effect. I want them to always be changing.

Comment: I see. In that case, for my answer, you should simply wrap the entire `each()` loop in this same `setInterval` you're already using. Arun's answer you've accepted is quite heavy as it creates a separate loop for each element iterated over - which is silly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .each() to iterate through a set of elements like

```js
$('.point').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var myVar = setInterval(function() {
    $this.css('opacity', Math.round(Math.random()));

  }, 50);
})
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400, 300|Roboto:400, 300, 100, 500|Dancing+Script:400, 700);
 .point {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: Black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="point"></div>
<div class="point"></div>
<div class="point"></div>
<div class="point"></div>
<div class="point"></div>
```

Comment: Ah thank you! Your code explained it well too. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: `Math.round(0.5)` will become `1`. Based on the code given in the question, OP wants `0.5` to be rounded down to `0`. `if (opacity > 0.5)
        opacity = 1;`

Comment: @JamesDonnelly yes, you are right.. In that case the ternary operator is the right choice

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jQuery's `each()` method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate through each of your `.point1` elements, then apply the `opacity` individually to each one:

```
$('.point').each(function() {
    $(this).css({ opacity: Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0 });
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zyqqLtk4/1/)

#### Code Snippet

```js
$('.point').each(function() {
    $(this).css({ opacity: Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0 });
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,300|Roboto:400,300,100,500|Dancing+Script:400,700);
.point {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: Black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="point"></div>
<div class="point"></div>
<div class="point"></div>
<div class="point"></div>
<div class="point"></div>
<div class="point"></div>
<div class="point"></div>
<div class="point"></div>
<div class="point"></div>
<div class="point"></div>
```